# Why are Karma tests failing after moving to Webpack 5?

Tags: webpack, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I have a set of karma tests which were passing with webpack v4.46.0 but they fail because of `spyOn` after moving to webpack v5.0.0.

A lot of tests spy on a module as follows:

```
import Module from '...';

...

beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(Module, 'getSomething').and.returnValue(true);
});
```

This was working fine, but moving to Webpack v5.0.0 (with karma-webpack v5.0.0) causes the following error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : getSomething has already been spied upon
```

Has some behavior changed, either in how `import` works or in how `spyOn` works, in the new version? I'm at a loss for why this would be breaking.